# Porque o ajax não funciona?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Tenho um código que faz o que quero, mas atualiza a página. Já tentei de várias maneiras usar ajax pra enviar os dados pro banco de dados, mas ainda assim não funciona, e tenho 3 perguntas sobre ajax:

1 - É possível criar uma sessão `$_SESSION` usando ajax?

2 - É possível usar essa sessão criada?

3 - Como o ajax realmente funciona?

Procurei em vários sites, varias teorias, e códigos, mas ainda estou engatinhando nisso, quero aprender, mas preciso de uma luz.
O que eu gostaria era um nome de enviando quando clicasse no botão de enviar, e mostrasse a mensagem que defini no php.

Estou usando bootstrap 4 css e js, e o jQuery 3.3.1

Olha meu código:

**index.php**

```
<form action="post.php" method="post">
  <p class="text-muted">Obs: Envie uma texto.</p>
  <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="text"</textarea>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
     $("#enviar").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
           dataType:'html',
           url:"post.php",
           type:"POST",
           data:({mensagem:$("input[name='text']").val(),

           beforeSend: function(data){ 

            }, success:function(data){
                alert("Dados Enviados");
            }, complete: function(data){}


           });
</script>
```

**E o post.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../../assets/tools/config.php");

$text = $_POST['text'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO textos (text) values ('$text')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Verificar se salvou no banco de dados 
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<script>setTimeout(\"swal({type: 'success',title: 'Sucesso..',text: 'Desafio Concluído Com Sucesso!'})\", 100) </script>";
    header("Location: ../");
} else {
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<script>setTimeout(\"swal({type: 'error',title: 'Erro..',text: 'Erro ao concluir desafio!'})\", 100) </script>";
    header("Location: ../");
}
```

Comment: Faltou o código do ajax.

Comment: Acabei de adicionar

Comment: A sintaxe do data está errada. Seria: `data:{mensagem:$("input[name='text']").val()},`

Comment: Além do que o @sam disse, tu precisa adicionar um `return false` ao enviar o formulário.

No evento `click`, adiciona `return false`, assim não vai redirecionar.

Comment: Chaves ao fechar o evento click ?

Comment: Pedro, esse "#enviar" não foi definido em momento algum no seu formulário, seu javascript não está sendo acionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ajax funciona como um intermediário/comunicador entre o seu HTML e PHP. Através dele você consegue atualizar dados da sua página sem necessariamente atualizá-la, pode enviar dados para o seu servidor por background, pode trazer mais dinamismo a sua aplicação, além de várias outras utilidades.

Para fazer a comunicação com o seu PHP, faça o seguinte:

```
<form id="form_text" name="form" method="post">
    <p class="text-muted">Obs: Envie uma texto.</p>
    <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" name="text"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //capture o evento de envio do seu formulário
    $("#form_text").on("submit",function(e){

        //bloqueia acao principal
        e.preventDefault();

        //capture o  bloco que sofreu o evento
        var form = $(this);

        //localize a variavel
        var texto = form.find('textarea[name="text"]').val();

        //envie os dados para o seu php
        $.post('post.php',{ text:texto }).done(function(res){
            //O retorno do seu PHP ficará armazenado em "res".
            console.log(res);                

            //transforme a string retornada do PHP para um objeto javascript
            var response = JSON.parse(res);

            swal({type: response.type,title: response.title,text:response.text});

        }).fail(function(err){

            swal("Erro Fatal",{icon:'warning'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

**O seu PHP**

```
$text = $_POST['text'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO textos (text) values ('$text')";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

//Verificar se salvou no banco de dados 
if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn)) {

    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success","title"=>"Sucesso","text"=> "Desafio Concluído Com Sucesso!"));

} else {

    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"error","title"=>"Erro","text"=> "Erro ao concluir o desafio!"));

}
```

Maiores informações você pode consultar na documentação do jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Se eu colo car o action="post.php" no form ele manda, mas atualiza a página e da esse erro 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/namorizando/app/regras/post.php on line 11;

Comment: A linha 11 é: echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success","title"=>"Sucesso","text": "Desafio Concluído Com Sucesso!"));

Comment: estou colocando o código js abaixo do jquery

Comment: sem o action não faz nada

Comment: Pedro, estava com um erro de sintaxe no PHP, a comunicação entre o ajax e o seu PHP está acontecendo pois o erro foi apontado pelo servidor. Toque "text" : por "text" =>

Comment: outro ponto também, esse código javascript deve ficar abaixo da sua chamada ao jQuery, no mínimo nessa ordem: <script src="jquery"> e depois <script> codigo </script>. Você também precisa colocar um ID no seu formulário, conforme o exemplo.

Comment: esse ID do formulário deve ser o mesmo utilizado no evento do javascript

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81006/discussion-between-pedro-henrique-and-gabriel-carvalho).